# Counting bases DNA chain sequence

Tags: python, count, sequence

How to write a code in python that reads a DNA sequence chain and return it's list of repeated bases describing these 3 things: which is the base (AGTC), it's position in the chain and how many times is repeated. For instance:

ACTTTTGTCTAAACCCCCCGTCCTATATATAACT

The output for this one is: list_bases =[('T',3,4),('A',11,3),('C',14,6)]

Comment: Could you explain the output a little bit further? I'm confused.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want us to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
DNA_seq = 'ACTTTTGTCTAAACCCCCCGTCCTATATATAACT'
count_dic = {'A': [0,0], "G": [0,0], "C": [0,0], "T": [0,0]}
for i in range(len(DNA_seq)-1):
    j=i
    seq_count = 1
    while DNA_seq[j] == DNA_seq[j+1]:
        seq_count +=1 
        j +=1
        if seq_count > count_dic[DNA_seq[i]][1]:
            count_dic[DNA_seq[i]][1] = seq_count
            count_dic[DNA_seq[i]][0] = i + 1
```

The content of count_dic is

```
{'A': [11, 3], 'G': [0, 0], 'C': [14, 6], 'T': [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

seq = "ACTTTTGTCTAAACCCCCCGTCCTATATATAACT"
bases = ['A','G','C','T']

indexes = defaultdict(list)
counts = dict()

for base in bases:
    comSeq = re.compile(base)
    matches = comSeq.findall(seq)
    count = len(matches)
    counts[base] = count

    start = 0

    for match in matches:
        index = seq.find(base, start)
        indexes[base].append(index)
        start = index +1

print(indexes)
print(counts)
```

The dict indexes gives you each position of the bases in the chain:

```
{'A': [0, 10, 11, 12, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31], 'G': [6, 19], 'C': [1, 8, 13, 14,
 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 32], 'T': [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 20, 23, 25, 27, 29, 33]}
```

The dict counts gives you the count of how many times the base occurs in the chain:

```
{'A': 9, 'G': 2, 'C': 11, 'T': 12}
```

It's probably not the best and efficient code and I wasn't sure what you were asking for, hope this helps anyway.